# PowerShell Script With Classes won't execute on Fresh Windows 10 Installation

Tags: powershell, windows-10

I am attempting to execute a PowerShell script that works fine on a windows 10 PC that has visual studio and all its dependencies installed, but it will not execute on a VM with a fresh installation of windows 10 pro.  I've chiseled the script down and determined that the thing it does not like is the definition of a class in the script.

```
Class Computer {
[String]$Name
[String]$Description
[String]$Type
[String]$Owner
}
```

The error I get when running the script with nothing but this class definition is:

> ```
> An error occurred while creating the pipeline.
> +CategoryInfo: NotSpecified: (:) [], ParentContainsErrorRecordException
> +FullyQualifiedErrorId: RuntimeException
> ```

Running `$PSVersionTable` on the fresh VM:

```
 Name                           Value
 ----                           -----
 PSVersion                      5.0.10240.16384
 WSManStackVersion              3.0
 SerializationVersion           1.1.0.1
 CLRVersion                     4.0.30319.42000
 BuildVersion                   10.0.10240.16384
 PSCompatibleVersions           {1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0...}
 PSRemotingProtocolVersion      2.3
```

Doesn't PowerShell 5.0 have support for classes? Am I missing a .NET framework dependency that isn't installed or enabled by default with a fresh Windows 10 installation?

Comment: 10240.16384 = 1st Win10 from 2015. Update to 1607 from august 2016 and look what happens

Comment: Also, replace those smart quotes with `'`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get the WMF 5.0 functionaly, please update to the November Update (10.0.10586.0) per [The WMF 5.0 release blog](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/powershell/2015/12/16/windows-management-framework-wmf-5-0-rtm-is-now-available/).

> Note: If you are running Windows 10, you can get the same set of functionality available in WMF 5.0 RTM by updating to the November update of Windows 10 (Version 1511). If you have not already updated your Windows 10 system, select the Start button, then select Settings > Update & security > Windows Update > Check for updates.

Comment: This was the issue. Thanks!